# Перенаправление с помощью с htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите написать код, чтобы, набирая `название-сайта.com/название-страницы`, перебрасывало пользователя на `название-сайта.com/?название-страницы`, но в адресе у пользователя ничего не менялось.

**Обновление**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} -f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[^\?](.+)  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://mydomen.com/\?$1 [L]
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://sitename.com?$1 [L]
```